# Как можно переименовать package?

Tags: android, java, package

Имя пакета `com.example.level.namis`. Мне нужно теперь поменять `example`. В студио выбираю Refactor -> Rename, но она позволяет переименовать только `level` на другое имя, а нужно поменять `example`. Не переименовывать же каждый файл  и папку тоже вручную.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Compact Empty Middle Packeges]

Ставишь галочку `Compact Empty Middle Packeges` и рефакторишь пакет. Вообще можно еще менять packageId в build.gradle.

Comment: Не факт, что у него intellij.

Comment: @gorets да, получилось переименовать, но Google play все равно говорит "Название пакета "com.example" недопустимо. Укажите другое". Хотя переименовать получилось.

Comment: Наверное, в build.gradle старые название остались.

Comment: @gorets да так и есть, спасибо, работает.

Comment: Не знаю, для какой версии студии был дан ответ, но в версии 2.3.2 для переименования частей пакета галочку нужно УБРАТЬ.

Comment: У меня ultimate intellij. И нет такой иконки.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно и толково. Но у меня получилось надо снять галочку Compact Empty Middle Packeges и потом поменять обязательно в ручную applicationID в build.gradle(Module: app)